# Get state of checkbox given its text

Tags: javascript, jquery

A form's checkbox is programmatically created with this html:

```
<div class="checkbox"><label for="household_assistances_10"><input id="household_assistances_10" name="household[assistances][]" value="10" type="checkbox">Other</label></div>
```

On the assumption that the id will be unique but its digits (e.g., 10) cannot be predicted, how can whether the box is checked be determined? I've tried a wide variety of selectors but not yet been successful.

Edit:

It is apparently not clear that I need to follow the state of the checkbox that shows as `Other`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("household_assistances_10").checked` ?

Comment: jQuery: `$('[type="checkbox"]:checked')` will list all checked checkboxes.... example: https://jsfiddle.net/ns9z7xa5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would handle this issue is by using a change event listener that checks for any checkboxes with an id that starts with 'household_assistances' and is checked. To do this you'll want to use the starts with selector:

> '[id^=household_assistances]'

This finds all controls with an Id that STARTS WITH household_assistances. Then you can further modify that selector with only checkboxes that are checked:

> '[id^=household_assistances]:checkbox:checked'

This will return any controls that are checkboxes, that are checked and have an id starting with 'household_assistances'.

Here is a working sample of how this implementation might look:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[id^=household_assistances]:checkbox:checked', function() {
  console.log(this.id);
        console.log(this.name)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="household_assistances_10">
<input id="household_assistances_10" name="household[assistances][]" value="10" type="checkbox">
Other
</label>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

---

**UPDATE**

Given that you need to find the control by the text "Other" inside it, I would use the following selector/function:

```
$(document).on('change', 'label:contains("Other")', function() {    
    var id = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
    console.log(id[0].id);
    console.log(id[0].name);
});
```

This works by finding an label elements that contain the text 'Other', then it looks inside that label element for the first checkbox. You can then do whatever you need to with that checkbox (see if it's checked, get the id, name, etc)...

Please note, there are some assumptions here. If there is more than one label with the text 'Other', it will run on each of them. Also, it assumes that the checkbox you're looking for will always be the only checkbox inside the found label.

You would also want to write something in to catch instances where no checkbox is found as it would otherwise throw an error as written.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the level of response. What none of these appear to do is determine the state of the checkbox marked specifically `Other` if that text is the only unique item known beforehand. For example, I know how to select based on the leftmost characters of an id, but what does it take to find `Other` and `is(':checked')` when iterating through the returned object?

Comment: Based on that new information, I'll edit my answer with how I'd handle that.

Comment: My ultimate solution is different, but I've accepted your answer. Mine turned out to be     `$(document).on('change', '[id^=household_assistances]', function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).parent().text()) === 'Other' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('DING DING!');
        }
    });` Except the app will eventually do something other than ring a bell!

Comment: That works too. In most cases it won't matter, but it's always a good idea to think about which method with use more memory.

Comment: Turns out your method is also more useful than mine. Your comment also led me to learn how to discover memory usage, which is also useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would be interested in VanillaJS solution, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
// For the purpose of this example - attach click event to the button element
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Get all checkboxes
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  // Consider using map instead of forEach
  // Iterate over the checkboxes
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  
    // Do something with each checkbox
    const isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    const id = checkbox.id;

    console.log(`Checkbox ${id} ${isChecked ? 'is' : 'is not'} checked`);
    
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="household_assistances_8">
    <input
      id="household_assistances_8" 
      name="household[assistances][]"
      value="10"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    Other
  </label>
  <label for="household_assistances_9">
    <input
      id="household_assistances_9" 
      name="household[assistances][]"
      value="9"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    Other
  </label>
  <label for="household_assistances_10">
    <input
      id="household_assistances_10" 
      name="household[assistances][]"
      value="10"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    Other
  </label>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="button"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the checkbox be always at the same place in the DOM tree?

If so, you can use CSS hierarchy and pseudo selectors to retrieve the nth element:

```
$("#myform div:nth(n) input")[0].checked
```